# Returning Json Object in Spring Boot but It is showing undefined

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is part of my javascript function which is making a call to controller

`$.post(filterServiceUrl, data, onFilterProductsSuccess, "json");`

Controller is getting called successfully

```
public @ResponseBody HomeLoanFilterServiceResponseDto filter(FilterModel model, ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<LoanDetailsDto> loans = new ArrayList<LoanDetailsDto>();
    LoanFilterServiceResponseDto response = new LoanFilterServiceResponseDto();
    response.setSuccess(true);
    response.setErrorMessage("");
    //Business Logic
    response.setLoans(loans);
    return response
```

}

After getting the response making call to function

`function onFilterProductsSuccess(serviceResponse) {
        alert("serviceResponse.IsSuccess: "+ serviceResponse.isSuccess)
 };`

The function is showing alert box `serviceResponse.IsSuccess: undefined`

Comment: Can you post the LoanFilterServiceResponseDto class structure?
Is there a method as "isSuccess" in ResponseDto class?

Comment: `public class LoanFilterServiceResponseDto {

 private boolean isSuccess;
 private String errorMessage;
 private List<LoanDetailsDto> loans; //getteres & setters} `

Comment: Please add getter and setter for isSuccess property

Comment: getters & setters are there for all three properties.

Comment: i guess it is serviceResponse.isSuccess() since you need to access the private attribute through getter.

Comment: You need to call for isSuccess() method then

Comment: Your method should be something like this: public boolean isSuccess(){return this.isSuccess;}

Comment: thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access to an private attribute directly. Your method should be something like this:

```
public boolean isSuccess(){
    return this.isSuccess;
}
```

So if you want to check if the response is succesful, you should add the () -call the public method which access the private one-

```
alert("serviceResponse.IsSuccess: "+ serviceResponse.isSuccess())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Response class.

```
    public class LoanFilterServiceResponseDto {
private boolean isSuccess;
private String errorMessage;
//private List<LoanDetailsDto> loans; //getteres & setters
 //

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return isSuccess;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    isSuccess = success;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}
}
```

This is the js method.

```
 function onFilterProductsSuccess(serviceResponse) {
    alert("serviceResponse.IsSuccess: "+ serviceResponse.isSuccess())
       };
```

Comment: nothing is wrong with your answer. I think both of us have posted the answer at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

your return entity is

> HomeLoanFilterServiceResponseDto

,but actually you return this

> LoanFilterServiceResponseDto

try to change another class

Comment: Ya that is typo but I am using the same LoanFilterServiceResponseDto